# How do the different services in Oracle SOA relate to each other?

Tags: oracle, soa, bea

I'm am trying to figure out how the Oracle "Layered Architecture Model" works, and I am very confused about what the business, data, and presentation do, and how they relate to each other. I have seen many diagrams showing how this should work, but some real world examples would be useful?

For example I am guessing that web applications are what Oracle calls "Composite applications" and that these web applications are built up of what Oracle calls "Presentation Services".

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a link to the documentation or diagrams which are confusing you.

Comment: @apc. I can't post the documents as they are from courseware that belong to a company I worked at. I have tried searching Oracle's technology network as well but there are no clear examples on there either

Comment: Okay, the problem is, you are using a term which doesn't appear to be a standard Oracle one (put it this way, the number one Google hit for `Oracle+"Layered Architecture Model"` is this question). Oracle's SOA suite doesn't deal with presentation, so are you really talking about ADF-BC/Faces? Fusion Middleware generally?

Comment: Since Oracle took over BEA alot of the terminology changed. I guess I'm looking for an answer from someone who has used OSB and knows Oracle SOA, as most of the information is not available on the web

Comment: Ah, well, I know almost nothing about the BEA side of things.  Perhaps you should edit your question and/or re-tag it to make it clear that you are interested in the BEA/Weblogic side of things.  Eventually Oracle will completely integrate the WLS stuff with SOA Suite (or discard the bits they don't want).  Until that happy day we are going to have to be very clear about what we mean by "Oracle SOA".

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer to the best of my knowledge:

1. **The `OSB` is BEA's `ALSB` overhauled**. The main purpose of this is the job of `ESB`. It sits between your presentation layer and rest of the application. It defines the boundaries of your application, and supports mediation between various units.
2. Your components and various subsystems that contain business logic (think of different departments in an organization) are termed `Composite`s. For instance, these composites could internally use BPELs to represent business logic, and use JCA for reaching out services (database, ejbs, etc.,) local to them.
3. These `Composite`s, if need to reach out to services outside their jurisdiction (sorry, could not think of a better word,) they need to contact the OSB.
4. Any internal requirements for a service mediation is satisfied by a `Mediator` (unfortunately, **this is OESB overhauled**)

As you can see, this is sort of a pathetic attempt by Oracle to sell both their original ESB solution, along with the products they bought from BEA. Let me tell you, nothing stops you from wiring your internal services in OSB itself (probably the ultimate direction of Oracle)

*I am sure you will be able to find out more after rereading, and working hands on. Request to please update your question with your findings.*