# Does Oracle have two ESB products: Aqualogic Service Bus AND Oracle Service Bus or did ALSB get merged into the Oracle SB product?

Tags: oracle, soa, osb, alsb

Does Oracle have two ESB products: Aqualogic Service Bus AND Oracle Service Bus or did ALSB get merged into the Oracle SB product?

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462316/how-do-the-different-services-in-oracle-soa-relate-to-each-other/5407670#5407670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, yes, strictly Oracle does have two service bus products.  [Wikipedia puts it this way:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Enterprise_Service_Bus)

> "Oracle Enterprise Service Bus (ESB)
>   should not be confused with Oracle
>   Service Bus (OSB). ESB was developed
>   by Oracle. OSB, formally known as
>   Aqualogic Service Bus, was acquired
>   when Oracle bought BEA Systems. The
>   two products are related and
>   interchangeable."

But that's not entirely correct.  Both products overlap but they have different feature sets.  In 11g the Oracle Enterprise Service Bus is being merged into Oracle's Service Component Architecture whereas the Aqualogic service bus is being maintained as a standalone component.

Answer (score 2):

Dont even worry about Aqualogic...Its Oracle Service Bus all the way now :)

Answer (score 0):

The product previously referred to as AquaLogic Service Bus is now referred to as Oracle Service Bus. This is the fully featured service bus that provides complex orchestration, and a lot of integration with infrastructure like backend databases, Oracle BPM and Tuxedo.

The product previously referred to as Oracle ESB is now referred to as Mediator within the Oracle SOA Suite. It is now typically used for two purposes - routing and translation of document formats. It's more lightweight in terms of configuration and functionality.